# Regexp Greek chars by number

Tags: ruby, regex, utf-8

I deal with strings that contain Greek and English (Latin) text. I'd like to use a regex to catch all the Greek words that contain 4 or more characters on them.

Using regexp manual I figure out that I can use \p{Greek} to grab all Greek words and \w{4,} in order to grab 4+ character words. However, these two don't work together, from various tests I made.

Is there any way to do what I want using 1 regexp expression? Strings are UTF-8 and come out of tweets.

Regards

Comment: Show us what is failing for you. I'm stuck at im`agining how you would need to combine these expression (afaict `\w{4,} specializes on `\p{Greek}` so why do you need both?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the UTF-8 pattern modifier?

```
/\p{Greek}{4,}/u
```