# Encoding To Utf8, I have some Ã‚Â

Tags: php, database, encoding

I realised a couple week ago that we had some weird character on some old listing that i have on our website

i have some character like this Ã‚Â that are equal to a dualquote (")
i have some character like ÃƒÂ¢??

I want to repair them but i dont know how.

Since when i use a preg_replace if i make this code

```
$text = 'this is a listingTitle Ã‚Â with an encoding problem';
$test = preg_replace("/Ã‚Â/",'"',$text);
echo$test;
```

$test will still have that encoding error in the string so it is like the preg_replace dont see the encoding problem.

is there some one that have an idea on what can i do to repair those encoding error ?
Or is there a way i should proceeded

Thanks

Edit Here--------------------------------------------------

Ok so what im trying to do now is to convert back each char to utf8 
And since for some reason my string are mixed with a few encoding..

So here is a string and a breakdown of the char making the string.

Milwaukee 2415-21 M12 Cordless Lithium-Ion 3/8Â Right Angle Drill/Driver Kit wi

and this is the break down

```
atChar[0] = 'M' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[1] = 'i' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[2] = 'l' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[3] = 'w' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[4] = 'a' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[5] = 'u' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[6] = 'k' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[7] = 'e' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[8] = 'e' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[9] = ' ' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[10] = '2' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[11] = '4' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[12] = '1' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[13] = '5' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[14] = '-' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[15] = '2' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[16] = '1' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[17] = ' ' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[18] = 'M' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[19] = '1' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[20] = '2' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[21] = ' ' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[22] = 'C' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[23] = 'o' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[24] = 'r' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[25] = 'd' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[26] = 'l' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[27] = 'e' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[28] = 's' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[29] = 's' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[30] = ' ' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[31] = 'L' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[32] = 'i' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[33] = 't' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[34] = 'h' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[35] = 'i' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[36] = 'u' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[37] = 'm' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[38] = '-' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[39] = 'I' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[40] = 'o' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[41] = 'n' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[42] = ' ' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[43] = '3' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[44] = '/' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[45] = '8' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[46] = 'Â' encoding is = UTF-8
atChar[47] = '' encoding is = 
atChar[48] = ' ' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[49] = 'R' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[50] = 'i' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[51] = 'g' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[52] = 'h' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[53] = 't' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[54] = ' ' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[55] = 'A' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[56] = 'n' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[57] = 'g' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[58] = 'l' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[59] = 'e' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[60] = ' ' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[61] = 'D' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[62] = 'r' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[63] = 'i' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[64] = 'l' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[65] = 'l' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[66] = '/' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[67] = 'D' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[68] = 'r' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[69] = 'i' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[70] = 'v' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[71] = 'e' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[72] = 'r' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[73] = ' ' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[74] = 'K' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[75] = 'i' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[76] = 't' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[77] = ' ' encoding is = ASCII
atChar[78] = 'w' encoding is = ASCII
```

what can i do now?

Comment: what happens if you decode the string to an ISO format? http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Comment: This `$test = $preg_replace("/Ã‚Â/",'"',$text);` should not have a `$` in front of `preg_replace`. Try it now with `$test = preg_replace("/Ã‚Â/",'"',$text);` and put a space in `echo$test;` no biggie but it does seperate your echo from your variable `echo $test;`

Comment: $text = 'this is a listingTitle Ã‚Â with an encoding problem';
    $test = utf8_decode($text);
now i get this 
this is a listingTitle Â with an encoding problem

Comment: @NicolasRacine Then you'll need a different type of function and check for characters that are not in the standard character set.

Comment: @Fred -ii- ok so what i should do is to check each char and if one is not in the correct character set i change it ? Sorry im not exactly sure what you mean

Comment: @NicolasRacine Something to the affect of 

`$text = 'this is a listingTitle Ã‚Â with an encoding problem'; 

preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z0-9]/s','',$text); echo $text;`

Comment: @NicolasRacine The above will just replace the characters with nothing. If you want to have it so it's a double quote then either use `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z0-9]/s','"',$text);` and if that gives you a problem, use `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z0-9]/s','&quot;',$text);`

Comment: @NicolasRacine To explain my example/comment is that, if there is a non-standard character that is not within the `a-z` - `A-Z` or numbers in the queried string, those characters will be replaced.

Comment: @NicolasRacine So, any luck?

Comment: yes Im on it,.  But the thing is i will lose the character that was intended to be there with your way.

So im trying to figure a way to do preg_match those non standard character then if they are non standard im going to try to check the encoding of those char and then from there il try to revert it to utf8

Comment: @NicolasRacine Then have a look at these answers on SO, may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/a/9102945/1415724 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920188/regexp-greek-chars-by-number/5920342#5920342

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check This PHP Class Encoding featuring popular Encoding in [github](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8)

Usage:

```
$utf8_string = Encoding::toUTF8($utf8_or_latin1_or_mixed_string);

$latin1_string = Encoding::toLatin1($utf8_or_latin1_or_mixed_string);
```

also:

```
$utf8_string = Encoding::fixUTF8($garbled_utf8_string);
```

Examples:

```
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÃ©dÃÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÃÃ©dÃÃÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÃÃÃ©dÃÃÃÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
```

will output:

```
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
```

UPDATE:

Check this :(i checked This Worked)

```
$output = 'this is a listingTitle Ã‚Â with an encoding problem';
$output = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $output);
echo($output);
```

Output:

```
this is a listingTitle with an encoding problem.
```

Output pic:

[image]

Comment: Hum Html Purifier is cool!

But it doesn't remove the encoding error. :(

Comment: 1- u `SET NAMES utf8` before insert data? 2- check `PhpMyadmin` and tell me what's your charset? 3- `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in apache conf.

Comment: Now I do, ( set UTF-8 ) but this is not the problem the data is already in the database now everything work fine.   but old listing have those kind of error.

My charset is utf-8_general_ci

Comment: It Does the same :S it output the string with ? rather than Â

Comment: @NicolasRacine Then check what your file(s) encoding are/is saved as. UTF-8 with or without BOM. That may make a difference. If you don't know how, find a copy of Notepad++ and open the file(s). It will show you what encoding it's saved under, if you look under the "Encoding" menu.

Comment: @NicolasRacine: your problem is `UTF-8` encoding saving page, if not please try new Update.

Comment: @sambora The listing save fine. i dont want to save the listing. I want to repair some old listing that have those encoding error
Fred-ii-Thanks i will look at that right away

Comment: @sambora yes i did check your update. but the thing is i would like to revert all wierd char to what it is intended to be. since i have ALOTS of listing it would take me foreever to just go on all listing and change them with what is missing.
your script in the picture will technicly remove all char that are not supposed to be there. right ?

Comment: @sambora You know what il use that like code you gave me there. at this point i feel like i tryed everything to revert those encoding. so il manage to try to make some preg_replace to reput all missing char that was supposed to be in my listing.    Thanks Sambora and every one else.

Comment: you saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I have also faced the same problem While fetching data from `xml` feeds in multiple languages.

After strugging I found a solution by creating everything in `utf8` encoding.

1) Database coalition and charset.

2) Database connetion.

3) html page type.

Comment: This is what i did at first. But it look like those error are in the database it self.

Comment: Yes it wouldn't work for already saved contents in database. For that either you have to update them. But from now onward new records will be fine.

Comment: Yes i know that, :) But the thing is i now need to try to fix those old listing that have some error on :S

Comment: Not 100 % sure, but in that case you will have to find first their actual encoding and then again translate to their actual language.