# special character to csv in php

Tags: php, csv, special-characters, encode

here is current way i'm doing for generate csv file in php,

```
$path = $url . 'temp/' .$filename.'.csv';
   fputcsv($fp, $heders, ",");

        foreach ($new_data as $line) {
            fputcsv($fp, $line, ",");
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

here is problem which i have,

this is data i have in data set,

```
Brüel & Kjæ, Type 4226, S/N: 2433646
```

[image]

when generate csv file it's change to this,

```
BrÃ¼el & KjÃ¦, Type 4226, S/N: 2433646
```

[image]

i need to get exactly same character to csv. 
please help me to solve this issue :(

Comment: I think, you forget to set charset settings to UTF-8.

Comment: can you please tel me how to add ?

Comment: please review Chandresh's answer, he already replied .

Comment: it's not working bro same get same result :(

Comment: is this encode problem ?

Comment: can you please update que as you tried utf8 in header.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, set UTF-8 before getting result for both mysqli query and header

```
1. $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

and

```
2.  header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: im using mssql PDO connection. how to set charset to that ?

Comment: @Ashan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names#answer-4361485

Comment: :( same not working i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744840/encoding-to-utf8-i-have-some-%C3%83-%C3%82

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code at the top of the file in php,

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Hope it will may helpful to resolve your issue.

Thanks.